# How to start making a website and how along with databses?

Tags: web

How do i actually start making a website? Every time I think of making a website I stuck as  from where should I start?Where to start writing a code?How to make it interactive? Hoping to get the answer that help me. 
I have tried in the past but I really want to make a website of my own as I am looking to start my online company.

Comment: Google this: `MERN Stack`. That might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use wordpress. It is content management system with milions of themes and plugins to do whatever you want for your own web site.

Comment: Then better to stick into http://w3schools.com for few days and study about html, css, javascript. Then you can be a web designer very easily. Then follow php and mysql from same website. This is how i become a web developer.

Comment: Thanxxx a lot:)